# How to have backup pam module

Tags: security, login, password, authentication

I am currently getting to understand PAM. Right now I use OTP and password, but I want to be able to use either OTP and password and if that fails then use my YubiKey and password. I am on Arch and my system-auth file in the pam.d directory looks like this:

```
auth      required  pam_oath.so     usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=30 digits=6 debug
auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
auth      optional  pam_permit.so
auth      required  pam_env.so

account   required  pam_unix.so
account   optional  pam_permit.so
account   required  pam_time.so

password  required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow
password  optional  pam_permit.so

session   required  pam_limits.so
session   required  pam_unix.so
session   optional  pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 3):

Arch is Linux PAM (which is different from Solaris PAM and FreeBSD PAM) and Linux PAM has means to skip rules, so one way to do this would be along the lines of

```
auth required pam_unix.so ... # password
auth [success=2 default=bad] pam_yubikey ...
auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_otp ...
auth required pam_deny.so
auth required pam_env.so
...
```

which for the yubikey if that works should jump two rules down (to the `env` and any subsequent auth setup steps) and for OTP one rule down for the same, otherwise denying the auth. I'm not sure what the `default` or other options for the `[...]` bits should be, so I set them to fail.

Another option is a substack, in the main rules file you would have something like:

```
...
auth substack otp-foo
auth substack yubikey-foo
...
```

and then additional `/etc/pam.d/{otp-foo,yubikey-foo}` files one would do the if-authgood-or-pam_deny. However, in this case both will be tried (Linux PAM works through all the substacks) unlike the previous example where if the yubikey works it skips the otp check.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I needed. I could really use a tutorial on the more advanced control values but haven't been able to find one as it seems most just doesn't explain the complex ones. Know of any documentation of this?

Comment: I just discovered that this doesn't work as intended as the default=bad will make sure that the module fails so even if the otp is correct it will fail

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what the defaults should be without your modules to test with. I mostly cribbed things from "PAM Mastery" by Michael W. Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from thrig I finally got it right, but his first solution didn't work because default=bad would make it so the stack would always fail. The way I did it was to make a 2fa substack. I tested this on su instead of system-auth this time. The su PAM file looks like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so
auth            substack        2fa
account         required        pam_unix.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
```

As you can see right after pam_unix I include the substack 2fa which looks like this:

```
auth sufficient pam_yubico.so id=35659 authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings debug
auth required   pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=30 digits=6 debug
```

Because it is in a substack the sufficient control value doesn't end the whole module stack only the substack. So now if my yubikey fails I can use OTP instead if I entered the right password.